# Syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: php, smarty

Никак не могу разобратся с синтаксисом функций

```
{include file='index.tpl'};
```

Ошибка 
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\index.php on line 23**

Это подключение шаблона с именем index.tpl?Шаблон создан

Comment: Ошибка не в шаблоне, а в файле index.php

Comment: Может неправильная установка Smarty?

Comment: @SverxnovA смотрите файл index.php на 23 строчке. Там ошибка. Или код файла index.php в студию :)

Comment: я не силен в Smarty и понимаю что внутри он работает с php, но что-то подсказывает, что подразумевается его работа в файлах "tpl", у вас include в файле "php" может в этом дело?